# $W$ is not equal to $W^{\perp\perp}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space with inner product. If $W$ is a **closed** subspace of $V$ we always have $W\subseteq W^{\perp\perp}$. Now, I found a proof where the equality holds if $V$ is Hilbert. It is an easy consequence of $V=W\oplus W^{\perp}$. So my question is if this is not true if $V$ is not Hilbert. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Thank you.

Edit: Oh, sorry if I didn't clarify. I'm still suppossing $W$ is closed.

Comment: In general $W^{\perp\perp}=\overline{W}$. Try your favourite Banach space that is not a Hilbert space, maybe you can find an example.

Comment: @Mathematician42 but it's given that $W$ is closed